Can't access 127.0.0.1 for my desmoscript project?
I am building a desmos graph with desmoscript, a text editor for desmos. The first time I ran it, it worked fine, but all subsequent times, I run the desmoscript HTTP server, and then click the link to 127.0.0.1
I then just get this message:

Thanks

That's not how it works. You need to get tampermonkey (or any other extensions like that) and the Desmoscript loader. Once you got the loader to work using tampermonkey, open desmos on a new tab, if there's a text box on the right corner, it means it has been properly loaded. Recompile it, and it should pretty much work on.

I did have tampermonkey, but when i pressed recompile, it just didn't load. I fixed it though, as it needed NodeJS to run
